# Clarification of the $MemberQ$

Tags: symbolic, pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, expression-construction, dot

There are a number of expressions:

```
expr1 = J.x. 1;

expr2 = x.J.x. (-P. 1);

expr3 = x.J.(Inverse[J].x. (-B.P. 1));

expr4 = x.J.(Inverse[J].x. (-B.P.(-1. B)));

expr5 = x.J.(Inverse[J].x. (-B.P.(A. (1. B.Transpose[B]).J)));
```

The $1$ is included in each of these expressions. But the `MemberQ` only defines it in the first one.

```
MemberQ[expr1, 1]
MemberQ[expr2, 1]
MemberQ[expr3, 1]
MemberQ[expr4, 1]
MemberQ[expr5, 1]
```

[image]

This is due to the fact that the `levelspec` is not specified. Is it possible to somehow automate the process so that the program can determine the occurrence of $1$ in the expression of an arbitrary structure without additional definition of the `levelspec`?

Comment: `Position[#, 1 | -1 | 1.] & /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4, expr5}` ?

Comment: ``MemberQ[list, form, \[Infinity]]``

Comment: `MemberQ[expr, form, All]` and `!FreeQ[expr, form]` also work

Answer (score 1):

Note that there must be a space between the dot and the "1". If one copies your input, the space disappears.

Then note that "MemberQ[expression,element]" without any level specified will only check in level 1 of expression. Therefore to make your second example work look at the expression tree of expr2:

```
ExpressionTree[expr2]
```

[image]

You see that "1" appears on level 3. Therere you must specify:

```
MemberQ[expr2, 1, 3]

(* True *)
```

To make life easier, you may also specify something like "all levels". This is written:

```
MemberQ[expr2, 1, Infinity]

(* True*)
```

Comment: The last string solves the problem. Is it possible to make an exception so that $1$ under the transposition function (for example `Transpose[___,1,___]` or `Transpose[1]` or `Transpose[-1]`) is excluded from consideration?

Comment: You could either restrict the level or use "Except" in the pattern: " 1 || Except[Transpose[{___ ,1 ,___}]] "

Comment: `MemberQ[1 + Transpose[1], 1 || Except[Transpose[1]], Infinity]` This construction did not work for this expression. Here he must exclude transposition, but since `1` stays beyond (like another term), should result in `True`, but shows `False`

Comment: Sorry, there should be only one bar: " 1 | Except[Transpose[{___ ,1 ,___}]] "  Alternatives in pattern require one bar and "or" in a logic expression needs two bars.